# Simple way to visualize First Cousin marriage

Tags: marriage-practices

I came across some **blood relations / intra family** marriages like *first cousin marriages* in some of my family history books that I have. They are all documented as text in a family history book, not as a pedigree. I tried [MyHeritage.com](http://myheritage.com) to draw such a tree, but no luck. I don't think I can loop back a child node to an ancestor and create a marriage relation, but has to create another duplicate tree.

Reading about [Albert Einstein's family history](http://phylonetworks.blogspot.com/2014/01/albert-einsteins-consanguineous-marriage.html), I came across such a [diagram](http://phylonetworks.blogspot.com/2014/01/albert-einsteins-consanguineous-marriage.html). Is this the right way to show a family tree which has first cousin marriages or is there a better way? Is there a software or website where I can do something like this?